# Run Python script with Automator // why does it only work if I include export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH and what does it mean?

Tags: python, bash, automator

I was trying to run a Python script via Mac's Automator and the command is very straight forward:

**"cd /Users/myname/Desktop/project && python3 myprojectapp.py".**

However, every time I tried to run it, Automator raised an error such as *ModuleNotFoundError*. This was however, impossible since I had all libraries (e.g. Pandas) installed and running the command in the Terminal as written above worked flawlessly.

Now, I've read somewhere for a similar problem to just include: 
**"export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH"** before the command and it worked. Now, before I go on with my life, I would like to understand what exactly this extra line does and how it affects Automator to the point of making the script work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command basically modifies the environment variable `PATH` and puts the directory `/usr/local/bin` before everything that is currently in `PATH`. However, that command is temporary, and the environment variable PATH is restored when the session closes.

What could be happening is the python you're running in terminal and the python Automator is running are different.`/usr/local/bin` probably contains the same python version as you are using in terminal. Take a look at `~/.bash_profile` to see if something similar to `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` is in there.

Another way to check is to type `which python` in both and see if it points to the same python. You probably have yet another python somewhere in the list of directories in your `PATH` variable.

It's common to use virtual python environments to keep track of which python is running and to experiment with python without messing with system python. Examples of these include: [Anaconda](https://anaconda.com) and [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/).

Comment: Ok, that does sound like what could be happening here. I am very glad that I did not mess anything up with running the command "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH".

Looking up the bash profile, I just see the Path is PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}". 

Shall I change, in Automator, the first command "export PATH" to the one I see in my bash profile? Like this:

**export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}**?

Thank you very much for your answer and your time!

Comment: Automator's **Run Shell Script** action (as well as AppleScript's **do shell script**) just use a default shell, which doesn't have any of the configurations used in **Terminal**.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that would be a good idea, and now you know where your python is if you need to run code in an IDE (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python`).